# async/await запрс к Api в React

Tags: reactjs, api

Я получаю из стейта массив с ключами. Мне нужно сделать запрос к апи по каждому из этих ключей и вывести карточку с данными по каждому ключу. Не могу понять, почему не работает. Создать функцию, а потом запустить в рендер? или сразу в рендер.

```
this.ProductsService.getProductsByKey(item.key) = это сам запрос, работает правильно. 

const myListProducts = 
  this.props.products.map(async (item) => {
    await this.ProductsService.getProductsByKey(item.key);
    return myListProducts;
  })
;
```

Comment: `map` не умеет в асинхронную итерацию. используйте `await Promise.all(this.props.products.map( ... тут генерация промиса ... ))`

Comment: т.е. `const res = Promise.all(this.props.products.map(this.props.products.map((item) => this.ProductsService.getProductsByKey(item.key))); const myListProducts = res.flat();`